# How to use the area around Macbook's notch in fullscreen?

Tags: swift, macos

I need to use the area around (and behind) the notch while application is in full screen mode and display my app "fully full-screen" and use that area to display elements, as if there is no notch there.

I understand that is where the menu bar appears, but I am okay with either disabling menu bar in full screen OR making it act like older macs when it would appear **over** the application after we move cursor higher in that area.

I've tried (to no avail):

- Playing with Safe Area
- Hiding Title Bar from inspection menu in Xcode
- Removing the Menu completely
- Adding UISupportsTrueScreenSizeOnMac = true to plist

P.S. I've already done hours of searching on Google and SO, as well as Apple's documentation but haven't found any indication of how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can use fullscreen mode to do this, because there is no public API for overriding your window's fullscreen frame to include the unsafe areas around the sensor housing (the ‘notch’).

You should be able to manually achieve this by looking at the [`NSScreen`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen) representing the built-in display. Set your window's `frame` to the screen's `frame` (**not** the screen's `visibleFrame`). The screen's [`auxiliaryTopLeftArea`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen) and [`auxiliaryTopRightArea`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/3882916-auxiliarytoprightarea) describe the areas to the left and right of the notch. From those, you can deduce the area obscured by the notch.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction! I did a quick test by: `override func windowDidLoad() {
 window!.toggleFullScreen(self)
 window!.setFrame(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1728, height: 1117), display: true)
}` and now the app actually does fill around the notch (in fullscreen) for like 1 second before resetting and moving lower, so I just need to figure out why it doesn't stick in that mode.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote about this recently in [my notes](https://notes.alinpanaitiu.com/Fullscreen%20apps%20above%20the%20MacBook%20notch) *(especially on how to do this from outside the app)*.

The key steps are:

1. Set your app [presentationOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428664-presentationoptions) to hide the menubar and dock
2. Make the window **borderless**
3. Set the window frame equal to the screen `frame` *(not `visibleFrame`)*

```swift
NSApp.presentationOptions = [.autoHideMenuBar, .autoHideDock]
window.styleMask = [.borderless]
window.setFrame(window.screen!.frame, display: true)
```

Comment: Any ideas or hints about how to make it work in macOS SwiftUI application (not the Frida approach, but by adding legacy full screen functionality to the app)?
When tried the code as is, on button click, an app crashes after (or because of) `window.styleMask = [.borderless]`. Without it, it only uses space below the notch.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to achieve this (simplified just for reference):

1. Hide application's "Title Bar"
2. Set your window's frame to full width and height on load (again, simplified)

> ```
> override func windowDidLoad() {
>     window!.setFrame(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: NSScreen.main!.frame.width, height: NSScreen.main!.frame.height), display: true)
> }
> ```

3. Set LSUIPresentationMode in your plist

> ```
> <key>LSUIPresentationMode</key>
> <integer>3</integer> // Change this to 4 if you want to allow menu bar and dock to appear when user moves cursor top/bottom edges (they are initially hidden)
> ```

---

**Note:**

Without using LSUIPresentationMode or even hiding title bar, the following code would launch the app in fullscreen and for ~1 second it would fill the area around notch as well, but then it would revert back to the area below notch.

Just thought I should also mention this, so there might be ways to achieve this while using native fullscreen

```
window!.toggleFullScreen(self)
window!.setFrame(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1728, height: 1117), display: true)
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it work in SwiftUI application on macOS 12.6 without success. A window doesn't expand to the notch-level area and stays below it (can be dragged there manually but automatically returns back immediately after). Anything specific needed about hiding Title Bar? I've tried `.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())` and `.windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution. But maybe helpful.

I tried swizzling `-[_NSFullScreenContentController reservesSpaceForMenuBarInFullScreen]` with retuning value `NO`.

```objectivec
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <objc/message.h>

void swizzle(Class class, SEL cmd, IMP custom, IMP _Nullable * _Nullable original) {
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, cmd);
    IMP originalImp = method_getImplementation(originalMethod);
    
    *original = originalImp;
    class_replaceMethod(class, cmd, custom, nil);
}

BOOL (*original_NSFullScreenContentController_reservesSpaceForMenuBarInFullScreen)(id, SEL);
BOOL custom_NSFullScreenContentController_reservesSpaceForMenuBarInFullScreen(id self, SEL cmd) {
    
    return NO;
}

@implementation NSWindow (Swizzle)

+ (void)load {
    
    swizzle(NSClassFromString(@"_NSFullScreenContentController"), NSSelectorFromString(@"reservesSpaceForMenuBarInFullScreen"), (IMP)&custom_NSFullScreenContentController_reservesSpaceForMenuBarInFullScreen, (IMP *)&original_NSFullScreenContentController_reservesSpaceForMenuBarInFullScreen);
}

@end
```

Here's the results.

- Before

[image]

- After

[image]

With swizzling `-[_NSFullScreenContentController reservesSpaceForMenuBarInFullScreen]` frame of window will be fit to screen. But I cannot find how to remove a black bar.